# How to render activeClassName style for a react-router-dom NavLink rendered within a material-ui button in a typescript environment?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am learning react and trying to set the style of a **react-router-dom** *NavLink* encapsulated inside a **material-ui** *Button*. I am using React with Typescript and a custom Webpack build.

The [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) states that this can be achieved by setting the *activeClassName* property.

In the code listing below I try setting the *activeClassName* on the button containing the *NavLink* component.

```js
import * as navbar from './NavBar.css';

const NavBarLinks = () => (
  <>
    <Button
      color="inherit"
      component={NavLink}
      activeClassName={navbar.highlighted}
      to="/about"
    >
      About
    </Button>
  </>
);
```

The highlighted css class is as follows:

```css
.highlighted {
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(174, 185, 28);
}
```

However, no bottom border is rendered. How do I get the *activeClassName* style to render for a **react-router-dom** *NavLink* rendered within a **material-ui** *Button* within a Typescript environment?

My build environment is configured as follows.

I have created a type declaration file for the stylesheet
and saved this in a folder referenced in *tsconfig.json*.

```js
export const active: string;
export const horizmenu: string;
export const highlighted: string;
```

My *tsconfig.json* includes the *typesRoot* configuration. This references the types folder where my css type declaration file is stored:

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types"]
```

My webpack development configuration is using *css-loader* to bundle css files under *src/app/*/*

```
 {
        // link css modules
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.resolve(constants.dir.SRC, 'app'),
        use: [
          { loader: require.resolve('style-loader') },
          {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              },
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ...
```

When I perform a Webpack development build I can see that the *NavBar.css* contents are picked up by the *css-loader* and embedded as a string in the bundle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work, but you are passing a class name, not a style, so I think you just need to make your `activeClassName` prop equal to "highlighted".

```
<Button
  color="inherit"
  component={NavLink}
  activeClassName="highlighted"
  to="/about"
 >
  About
</Button>
```

You'll also need to add `!important` to you style so it overrides the CSS of the Material UI button.

Working codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-pond-vr132)

Comment: Many thanks @bgaynor78. Just checked out the codesandbox link. This is very useful and has given me some hope :) Ok, it seems that I am almost there and on the right track... However, I am using a custom webpack build with typescript, hence the different syntax for the _activeClassName_ attribute. I tried adding _important!_ and activeClassName="highlighted" but still does not render as expected. Problem must be somewhere in my build environment. Apologies, will update question with build environment....

Comment: Got it, did a typo with important! instead of !important. This did the trick @bgaynor78. Many thanks....accepting answer :)